# Jquery version conflict

Tags: web, jquery

I am using bootstrap framework for my website but there is a problem if I load 2 Jquery file at the same time. jquery.1.8.3.min.js and
jquery.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/grid.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                Grid.init();
            });
        </script>
```

How can I use this two files at the same time.

Comment: Why would you even want to? I don't think it's possible as both use the same namespaces, classes etc. etc. you could try to load the first one and use [this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) to assign it a different identifier than `$` but I doubt it will work.

Comment: Yes, why indeed. jQuery offers good compatibility, so there should be no issues with upgrading to a new minor version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will conflict. I've had issues where functionality has been depreciated in 1 version (which I needed) yet I need functionality of a latter version. You need to remove the conflicting Javascript from the library (if license allows) or only reference 1 version